# Openshift: Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS in .htaccess is doing a 302 redirect instead of rewriting

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having [my website](http://atlantiretireonline.com) automatically Rewrite to `HTTPS`. It is going to `HTTPS` from `HTTP`, but it is doing a 302 redirect instead of Rewriting. I just want to Rewrite and not do a redirect.

I have my code below.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a permanent redirect (301). You can do that with the following.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Other than that, you can also make port 443 the default port for incoming traffic, and enable that in your webserver settings. The code does the job though, and it counts as a permanent redirect.